# Upgrade to a new Raspbian version offline

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

Regular Debian produces "point release" CD images periodically that can be used in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to update systems offline.

Is there any way to upgrade to a newer release of Raspbian in a similar fashion, e.g. from Buster 2019-06-20 to Buster 2019-07-10? I suspect there aren't any sort of pre-made images for this, but if there's a way to create a "portable update repository" myself (i.e. get a list of packages updated in the new release, download them all onto a USB drive somehow, and be able to `apt-get upgrade` any Raspbian install from it), that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any such files.

If you want to upgrade several SD Cards you could try the procedure I use; upgrade one system then use rsync to update other SD Cards.

This is faster than copying an image. Depending on your use cases you may want to exclude some files e.g. hostname, cmdline.txt, /etc/fstab